# call for help of installing crypto libs in linux in order to program kerberos

Tags: encryption, kerberos

I am integrating kerberos to our project, first I have deployed a KDC server, and then I want to test if it works, so I used kerberos telnet to test, but I received following error msg:

```
Escape character is '^]'.
>>>TELNET: I support auth type 2 6
>>>TELNET: I support auth type 2 2
>>>TELNET: I support auth type 2 0
>>>TELNET: I support auth type 1 2
>>>TELNET: I support auth type 1 0
>>>TELNET: I will support DES_CFB64
>>>TELNET: I will support DES_OFB64
Waiting for encryption to be negotiated...
>>>TELNET: auth_send got: 02 06 02 02 02 00
>>>TELNET: He supports 2
>>>TELNET: Trying 2 6
telnet: calling krb5_sname_to_principal
telnet: done calling krb5_sname_to_principal
telnet: Kerberos V5: failure on credentials(KDC has no support for encryption type)
>>>TELNET: He supports 2
>>>TELNET: Trying 2 2
telnet: calling krb5_sname_to_principal
telnet: done calling krb5_sname_to_principal
telnet: Kerberos V5: failure on credentials(KDC has no support for encryption type)
>>>TELNET: He supports 2
>>>TELNET: Trying 2 0
telnet: calling krb5_sname_to_principal
telnet: done calling krb5_sname_to_principal
telnet: Kerberos V5: failure on credentials(KDC has no support for encryption type)
>>>TELNET: Sent failure message
>>>TELNET: Request input to be encrypted
>>>TELNET: He is supporting DES_CFB64 (1)
>>>TELNET: He is supporting DES_OFB64 (2)
>>>TELNET: (*ep->start)() returned 7

Negotiation of authentication, which is required for encryption,
has failed.  Good-bye.
```

It seems that my KDC doesn't support certain encryt algorithms, so I want to ask is there a all-purpose crypt library I can install in linux and unix? If there exists one, please tell me, I want to install it and make my KDC work, thank you.

Comment: Setting up even telnet to do kerberos auth isn't straight forward, are you sure everything is configured properly on the server side, and the proper service principals are created and extracted to your keytabs ?

Comment: yes, I am using host A as telnet client, host B as telnet server, and host C and host D as KDC server, the problem is that when I use host D as KDC, everything works fine, A can telnet to B via tickets, and klist displayed correct credentials, but when I switch KDC to host C, I got the above problems, so I wonder if A missing some cryto libs....

Answer (score 0):

Kerberized telnet (among the many, many other problems that it has) only supports DES.  DES is disabled in all modern Kerberos implementations because it's too weak.  If you really want to use Kerberized telnet, you probably have to enable DES with:

```
allow_weak_crypto     = true
```

in `[libdefaults]` in `/etc/krb5.conf`.  You'll also need to enable it on the KDC, and ensure that the server keytab has a DES key.

But, really, don't.  Just use ssh instead.  Current versions of OpenSSH support Kerberos authentication, support modern enctypes, and don't have any of the problems of Kerberized telnet.

(You're not missing any libraries.  The error message you're getting is the standard message for Kerberos applications trying to use DES when DES is disabled.)